# Generic JavaScript method which invokes other methods based on the arguments

Tags: javascript, methods, dojo

I've a Javascript method which expects two arguments - 1st one is the name of a function that should be executed and second one is array of params which I need to pass to to the function that I need to execute.
Basically I need to make this a generic function. Can I achieve this in a much efficient way using Dojo? Below is my function.

```
function UserDetails(){

    this.invokeCustomFunction=function(fnToBeExecuted,arraysOfParams){
        //This function is expectetd to execute the "fnToBeExecuted" and pass the "arraysOfParams" to it.
    }

    this.getUserDetails=function(userName){

    }

    this.getSalaryDetails=function(userId,EmployerName){

    }
}
//This is how I invoke it.
UserDetails userDetails=new UserDetails();
userDetails.invokeCustomFunction("getUserDetails","Sally");
userDetails.invokeCustomFunction("getSalaryDetails",["Sally","ATT"]);
```

Comment: I've used something like this in the past: `window['UserDetails']['getUserDetails'](arguments here)` to invoke a function, but I'm not sure about the "arguments here" part :) -EDIT- Note that I used this with variables, so it made sense lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
dojo.declare("UserDetails", null, {

    invokeCustomFunction : function(fnToBeExecuted,arrayOfParams){
        if (arrayOfParams instanceof Array) {
            dojo.hitch(this, fnToBeExecuted).apply(dojo.global, arrayOfParams);
        } else {
            dojo.hitch(this, fnToBeExecuted)(arrayOfParams);   
        }
    },

    getUserDetails : function(userName){
        console.log("getting user details for ", userName);
    },

    getSalaryDetails : function(userId,EmployerName){
        console.log("getting salary details for ", userId);
    }
});

var userDetails=new UserDetails();
userDetails.invokeCustomFunction("getUserDetails","Sally");
userDetails.invokeCustomFunction("getSalaryDetails",["Sally","ATT"]);
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/Zqp3h/9/

Answer (score 7):

Your example doesn't make it clear why you'd want to do this, but if you really do, then:

```
this.invokeCustomFunction=function(fnToBeExecuted,arraysOfParams){
    this[fnToBeExecuted].apply(this, arraysOfParams)
}
```

Comment: +1 here's the [`apply` function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply).

Comment: @Apps Yep, and the very similar [jQuery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/). They all use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply) internally.

Comment: @Apps: The difference is that the "real work" of dojo.hitch is concatenating the initial partial arguments - in your case you just skip directly to the function.apply

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a custom function for this.

You just need indexer notation:

```
userDetails["getUserDetails"]("Sally");
userDetails["getSalaryDetails"]("Sally", "ATT");
```

Comment: It's not necessary to put a simple string literal in square brackets. Your example is identical to `userDetails.getUserDetails("Sally");`

Comment: @N3dst4: I know.  However, I strongly assume that the point of his question is that that will be a variable.

Comment: You're right. I'll leave my comment as a note to future generations though.